# What have we to use with and/or?

Tags: conjunctions, subject-verb-agreement

What have we to use with **and/or** together?

> - John **and** Tim **have** to visit Anna next week.
> - John **or** Tim **has** to visit Anna next week.
> - John **and/or** Tim ____ to visit Anna next week.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134703/using-a-singular-or-plural-verb-after-and-or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no consistent rule in this situation:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134703/using-a-singular-or-plural-verb-after-and-or

The most advocated approaches are:

- The proximity rule: the verb is governed by the element nearest to it
- The "standard convention": if at least one element is plural, the verb must be plural too

So, in your case, it's "John and/or Tim has to visit Anna next week".